# Can't get Django custom user model to work with admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I created a custom user model (following this [writeup](http://buildthis.com/customizing-djangos-default-user-model/)), and I manage to get the signup and login to work. However, I'm having trouble logging into admin. Specifically, even after "successfully" created a superuser, I'm unable to login to the admin and got error message: "Please enter the correct email address and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

For the sake of completeness, I'm attaching the following code. I know it's a lot but any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks!!

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email),
                          )
        user.is_active = True
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email=email, password=password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Custom user class.
    """
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True, db_index=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email
```

custom backend in backends.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import check_password
from account.models import User

class EmailAuthBackend(object):
    """
    A custom authentication backend. Allows users to log in using their email address.
    """

    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
        """
        Authentication method
        """

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            else:
                print('Password not correct')
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            print('User does not exist')
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            if user.is_active:
                return user
            return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm, ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from .models import User as AuthUser
from django import forms


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """ A form for creating new users. Includes all the required fields, plus a repeated password. """
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password Confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = AuthUser
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        #Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        #Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label="password",
                                         help_text="""Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this
                                         user's password, but you can change the password using <a href=\"password/\">
                                         this form</a>.""")

    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = AuthUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class AuthUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm

    list_display = ('email', 'is_superuser')
    list_filter = ('is_superuser',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_superuser')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_superuser')}
        ),
    )

    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)

admin.site.register(AuthUser, AuthUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute that controls access to the admin is `is_staff`, not `is_admin`.

If you wanted to keep your current field for whatever reason, you could define an `is_staff()` method and make it a property.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Django to 1.9 version. I had resolved this issue using:

```
$ pip install django==1.9b1
```